# angular2 dynamic form calculate amount total

Tags: angular, dynamic-forms

Trying to calculate a total payOffs.amount (payOffs is a FormArray). Not sure how to do it properly so the total would observe changes to current and new for amounts. Here is a plnkr that I took as a base code:  http://plnkr.co/edit/nHSIsciSZNTQzQjxkXsk?p=preview

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="myModel.name" placeholder="Name">

<p>Pay Offs</p>
<table class="simple-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Final?</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let po of form.find('payOffs').controls; let i = index">
    <td>
      <input type="text" size=10 [formControl]="po.controls.amount" [(ngModel)]="myModel.payOffs[i].amount">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" [formControl]="po.controls.date" [(ngModel)]="myModel.payOffs[i].date">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="po.controls.final" [(ngModel)]="myModel.payOffs[i].final">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="deletePayOff(i)" style="color: white; background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5)">x</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; padding: .5em;">
    <button (click)="addPayOff($event)" style="color: white; background: rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)">Add Pay Off</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers:  []
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  myModel:any;

  constructor() {
    // initializing a model for the form to keep in sync with. 
    // usually you'd grab this from a backend API
    this.myModel = {
      name: "Joanna Jedrzejczyk",
      payOffs: [
        {amount: 111.11, date: "Jan 1, 2016", final: false},
        {amount: 222.22, date: "Jan 2, 2016", final: true}
        ]
    }

    // initialize form with empty FormArray for payOffs
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      payOffs: new FormArray([])
    });

    // now we manually use the model and push a FormGroup into the form's FormArray for each PayOff
    this.myModel.payOffs.forEach( 
      (po) => 
        this.form.controls.payOffs.push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(po))
    );
  }

  createPayOffFormGroup(payOffObj) {
    console.log("payOffObj", payOffObj);
    return new FormGroup({
      amount: new FormControl(payOffObj.amount),
      date: new FormControl(payOffObj.date),
      final: new FormControl(payOffObj.final)
    });
  }

  addPayOff(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // ensure this button doesn't try to submit the form
    var emptyPayOff = {amount: null, date: null, final: false};

    // add pay off to both the model and to form controls because I don't think Angular has any way to do this automagically yet
    this.myModel.payOffs.push(emptyPayOff);
    this.form.controls.payOffs.push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(emptyPayOff));
    console.log("Added New Pay Off", this.form.controls.payOffs)
  }

  deletePayOff(index:number) {
    // delete payoff from both the model and the FormArray
    this.myModel.payOffs.splice(index, 1);
    this.form.controls.payOffs.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you could observe changes on the whole form array, by subscribing to the changes in the constructor.

```
this.form.controls.payOffs.valueChanges.subscribe((change) => {
  const calculateAmount = (payoffs: any[]): number => {
    return payoffs.reduce((acc, current) => {
       // also handling case when a new pay off is added with amount of null
       return acc + parseFloat(current.amount || 0);
    }, 0);
  }

  console.log(calculateAmount(this.form.controls.payOffs.value));
});
```

Comment: I added @danny's console.log() to my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5HYcpnPQosSYvk2KkoP?p=preview

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, it works! Another question: how can I display total the same way in the form?

Comment: @Alla you could save result of the reduction into the component's property and display it on the form. Check out Andriy's solution with plunkr, it displays total in the table.

Comment: Thanx @danny. Do you guys have a skype or smth?

Answer (score 0):

I added a function:

```
// calculate a sum of all payoffs
sumPayOffs() {
  return this.myModel.payOffs.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val.amount, 0);
}
```

and in HTML (just before "Add Pay Off" button) I added readonly number field, displaying the sum:

```
<td>
  <input type="number" step="0.01" class="sum" readonly size=6 [value]="sumPayOffs()">
</td>
<td colspan="3" style="text-align: center; padding: .5em;">
  <button (click)="addPayOff($event)" 
          style="color: white; background: rgba(0, 150, 0, 1)">Add Pay Off</button>
</td>
```

I changed pay offs field type from *text* to *number*, so inserted into mode value will be numeric.

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5HYcpnPQosSYvk2KkoP?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @Andriy!

Comment: I am also trying to include total into the model and form control. Model is working fine, but control isn't displaying values.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please update your or my plunker (which should display both mentioned values) and point me to the problem, I will try to help