# How to sum up three form values automatically and result would be filled to another form input automatically in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a requirement as four form inputs which take only numbers as input, the three form inputs should be summed and add that sum to fourth form input.  As code says if Upper capacity, lower capacity, and Ac capacity has filled the sum of these three fields output must be filled in Total capacity. How can I achieve it in angular 4. I am new to angular.

```
  In TS file I wrote as
  UDC: number=0;
  LDC: number=0;
  ACC: number=0;
  TSC: number=this.UDC+this.LDC+this.ACC;
 But TSC is getting sum value it is taking only UDC value.

<div class="form-group">
            <label for="upperDeck_Capacity" class="control-label col-sm-4">Upper D Capacity</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input  OnlyNumber="true" class="form-control" placeholder="0" formControlName="upperDeck_Capacity" [(ngModel)]='UDC' >
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-7">
        <label *ngIf="registrationForm.get('upperDeck_Capacity').invalid && processValidation" [ngClass] = "'error'">Upper deck capacity is required. </label>
        </div></div>
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="lowerDeck_Capacity" class="control-label col-sm-4">Lower D Capacity</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input OnlyNumber="true" class="form-control" placeholder="0" formControlName="lowerDeck_Capacity" [(ngModel)]='LDC'>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-7">
            <label *ngIf="registrationForm.get('lowerDeck_Capacity').invalid && processValidation" [ngClass] = "'error'">Lower deck capacity is required. </label>
         </div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ac_Capacity" class="control-label col-sm-4">AC Capacity</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input OnlyNumber="true" class="form-control" placeholder="0" formControlName="ac_Capacity" [(ngModel)]='ACC'>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-7">
            <label *ngIf="registrationForm.get('ac_Capacity').invalid && processValidation" [ngClass] = "'error'">AC capacity is required. </label>
        </div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="total_Seat_Capacity" class="control-label col-sm-4">Total Capacity</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" formControlName="total_Seat_Capacity" [(ngModel)]='TSC'>
            </div><div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-7">
            <label *ngIf="registrationForm.get('total_Seat_Capacity').invalid && processValidation" [ngClass] = "'error'">Total seat capacity is required. </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn some details about the expected format of questions on the site. As it is, this question is asking for a solution. The expectation of most questions on Stack Overflow is you have made some effort into a solution and have run into an issue, with your question being about the specific issue. Please attempt to solve this problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: @Vikas As per your request i modified my question and given maximum info

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453105/angular2-dynamic-form-calculate-amount-total